# Fmask 4.0 on Sentinel data from Sinergise/AWS

Tags: sentinel-2, amazon-web-services

I have downloaded Sentinel data from the AWS bucket on S3. How can I place this into the appropriate SAFE folder structure to run the Fmask cloud masking software (https://github.com/GERSL/Fmask)?

[image]

Comment: Which tool are you using for downloading the data?

Comment: The AWS CLI (command line interface). For example:
`aws s3 cp --request-payer requester s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/tiles/tiles/37/Q/ED/2017/1/12/0/B01.jp2 /path/to/my/folder/B01.jp2`

Comment: That approach will just download the files directly. I am not experienced with the AWS CLI, but the sentinelhub.aws tool has the '-e' flag (exemplified by: 'sentinelhub.aws --tile T54HVH 2017-04-14 -e') which will recreate the .SAFE format and download that.

Comment: Mikkel: This is great, thank you. Make this an answer instead of a comment and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Sentinel-2 data is downloaded directly from the aws bucket, it comes in a digested format.
In order to recreate the `.SAFE` structure, a different tool should be used. The people behind storing Sentinel-2 data on AWS have created a tool set for that. The tool can found [here](https://github.com/sentinel-hub/sentinelhub-py) and the key usage is as follows:

```
sentinelhub.aws --tile T54HVH 2017-04-14 -e
```

Where the `-e` is a flag that triggers the recreation of the `.SAFE` structure for the downloads.

Comment: "-e" apparently stands for "entire". That is, download the "entire" product in a SAFE folder structure.